# Lazy Loading ngModules with own routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-loader

I have this scenario.

I have two Angular Modules: `AuthModule` and `DashModule`. Each of these modules have their own `.routing.ts`files.

Then, each of the modules are imported into the `AppModule` at the appwide level.

In code, here:

`auth.module.ts` is at `src/app/auth/auth.module.ts`

`auth.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
... // all necessary imports
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-module.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    // all declarations
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class AuthModule { }
```

`src/app/auth/auth-module.routing.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// all necessary imports

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'not-verified', component: NotVerifiedComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginRegisterComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: LoginRegisterComponent },
    { path: 'verify-email/:token', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
    { path: 'reset-password/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponenet },
    { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent },
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

The `DashModule` also follow a similar pattern as the `AuthModule`

My `src/app/app.routing.ts` looks like this:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './pages/notfound/notfound.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
  // this is more like a catchall route. if all routes fail
  {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent },
];

export const AppRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My `src/app/app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRouting } from './app.routing';

import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { DashModule } from './dash/dash.module';
// Providers
// some providers

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AuthModule,
    DashModule,
    AppRouting
  ],
  exports: [  ],
  providers: [
   // providers here
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, can I make both the `DashModule` and `AuthModule` lazy load? How?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loaded-routing? You'd probably find it easier with a single root route for each module.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have, except I still don't understand what it means. And by "single route for each module", you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazily loaded modules are not imported into the `app.module`. Remove them from there, otherwise, they will not be lazy loaded. In your `app.routing.ts` you need to define the routes and lazy load the modules there using something like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'dashbobard', loadChildren: 'src/app/dash/dashmodule.module#DashModule' },
  // or use relative paths.
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule },
];
```

If you're switching your application to lazily load modules, you might have to fix some of your routes, eg `[routerLink]='[/some/route]'`

Comment: Weird enough, now, all my routes are blank. No error, just blank.